# Как сделать чтобы удалить стардартный border и box-shadow эффект bootstrap-4 которое появляется после клика

Tags: css, bootstrap

```css
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #DEC746 !important;
  border-color: #DEC746 !important;
  color: #000 !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  padding: 12px 30px !important;
  border-radius: 35px !important;
}
center {
  display: block;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}


.btn_link {
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<center>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn_link">Download CV</a>
</center>
```

Как видно при клике вокруг кнопки поялвяется **синий** `border`.

> Вопрос как можно отменить данное действие или хотя бы перезаписать

таким образом чтобы появилось **желтый** `border`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important; //для отключения
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #DEC746 !important;//для жёлтого цвета
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое